# If $t\mapsto \rho(t)=e^{(1-t)A}\cdot e^{tB},$ then $e^{A}-e^{B}=\int^{t}_{0}e^{(1-t)A}(A-B)e^{tB}dt$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Suppose 
\begin{align}A,B\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R}),\;\forall\;\;n\geq 2\end{align}
We define 
\begin{align}\rho:\Bbb{R}\to M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{R})\end{align}
\begin{align}t\mapsto \rho(t)=e^{(1-t)A}\cdot e^{tB}\end{align}
I want to prove two statements

1.
\begin{align}e^{A}-e^{B}=\int^{1}_{0}e^{(1-t)A}(A-B)e^{tB}dt\end{align}
2. \begin{align}\forall\,r>0,\exists\,c(r)>0\;\text{such that}\end{align}
\begin{align}\Vert e^{A}-e^{B}\Vert \leq c(r)\Vert A-B\Vert,\;\text{for}\;\Vert A\Vert\leq r,\Vert B\Vert\leq r\end{align}

MY THOUGHTS:

Based on the fact that I'm currently studying Basic Theory of ODE, I'm thinking this might have something to do with

1. Gronwall's Lemma
2. Mean Value Theorem
3. Local or global Lipschitzian

MY TRIAL

Number 2:

\begin{align}A,B\in M_{n\times n}\end{align}
implies that $A,B$ are continuous since $M_{n\times n}$ is isomormphic to $\ell (\Bbb{R}^n)$, that is, a space of continuous linear maps.

Then,
\begin{align}\Vert e^{A}-e^{B}\Vert&=\big\Vert\int^{1}_{0}e^{(1-t)A}(A-B)e^{tB}dt\big\Vert\\
&\leq \int^{1}_{0}\Vert e^{(1-t)A}(A-B)e^{tB}\Vert dt\\
&\leq\Vert A-B\Vert \int^{1}_{0}\Vert e^{(1-t)A}\Vert\Vert e^{tB}\Vert dt\end{align}
I got stuck at this point. Please, any help about the this and the first one?

Comment: Your integral should be between 0 and 1. It does not make any sense to have $t$ as the integration variable and in the integration boundaries.

Comment: @yultan: Sorry, I'll edit!

Comment: @yultan: I think the question was posted wrongly for limits between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, for 1/ you just need to expand the two inner exponnentials, use the Cauchy product and integrate. For 2/, $||e^X|| \le e^{||X||}$ and a compactness argument should do the trick.

Comment: @yultan: Wow! Show me!

Comment: Yes, it changes everything. It would become a fonction of $t$. Also, I will not do  your homework :)

Comment: @yultan: "Also, I will not do your homework", smiles... It's a build-up exercise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

$\rho(t) = e^{(1 - t)A}e^{tB}, \tag 0$

we have

$\rho(1) = e^B, \tag 1$

$\rho(0) = e^A; \tag 2$

thus,

$e^B - e^A = \rho(1) - \rho(0) = \displaystyle \int_0^1 \dot \rho(s) \; ds; \tag 3$

from (0),

$\dot \rho(t) = e^{(1 - t)A}(-A)e^{tB} + e^{(1 - t)A}Be^{tB} = e^{(1 - t)A}(B - A)e^{tB}; \tag 4$

we substitute (4) into (3):

$e^B - e^A = \displaystyle \int_0^1 e^{(1 - s)A}(B - A)e^{sB} \; ds, \tag 5$

and negate:

$e^A - e^B = \displaystyle \int_0^1 e^{(1 - s)A}(A - B)e^{sB} \; ds; \tag 6$

that's the first one.

For the second,

$\Vert e^A - e^B \Vert = \left \Vert  \displaystyle \int_0^1 e^{(1 - s)A}(A - B)e^{sB} \; ds \right \Vert \le \displaystyle \int_0^1 \left \Vert e^{(1 - s)A}(A - B)e^{sB} \right \Vert \; ds$
$\le \displaystyle \int_0^1 \left \Vert e^{(1 - s)A} \right \Vert \left \Vert A - B \right \Vert \left \Vert e^{sB} \right \Vert \; ds = \Vert A - B \Vert \displaystyle \int_0^1 \left \Vert e^{(1 - s)A} \right \Vert \left \Vert e^{sB} \right \Vert \; ds$
$\le \Vert A - B \Vert \displaystyle  \int_0^1 e^{(1 - s) \Vert A \Vert} e^{s \Vert B \Vert} \; ds \le  \Vert A - B \Vert \displaystyle  \int_0^1 e^{(1 - s)r}e^{sr} \; ds  = e^r  \Vert A - B \Vert. \tag 7$

Comment: Truly, you love mathematics! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Micheal:  Yuppers yuppers yuppers!  And thanks to you as well!  Cheers!

Comment: You might want to see this! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897728/if-rho-bbbr-to-m-n-times-n-bbbr-then-rhot-left-rhot-right

Comment: @Micheal:. checking it out!